# Get and validate the DNS domain name in .Net

Tags: c#, python, url, dns

Basically if I want to get the root of domain and check it in C#, is there any library similar to publicsuffix2  in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try [Nager.PublicSuffix](https://github.com/tinohager/Nager.PublicSuffix).

In Python using `publicsuffix2`:

```
from publicsuffix2 import get_public_suffix

suffix = get_public_suffix("www.google.com")
print(suffix)   # Should return google.com
```

In C# using `Nager.PublicSuffix`:

```
var domainParser = new DomainParser(new WebTldRuleProvider());
var domainName = domainParser.Get("www.google.com");
Console.WriteLine(domainName.Hostname); # Should return google.com
```

The package is available on NuGet.